# Mocking inherited class with Moq

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, moq

I have some Web API methods that I want to write unit tests for. They need database access, so, naturally, I wanted to Moq that part.

The storage classes are accessed via an interface, and the class that implements the API method inherits the interface. What I don't know is how to mock is the inherited interface in a unit test.

```
public class CreateWishList : APIAccess
{
    public long CreateWishListV1(long userId, string wishListName)
    {
        // Do stuff like
        long result = Storage.CreateWishList(userId, wishListName);

        return result;
    }
}

public class APIAccess
{
    protected IStorage Storage { get; private set; }

    public APIAccess() : this(new APIStorage()) { }

    public APIAccess(IStorage storage)
    {
        Storage = storage;
    }
}

public interface IStorage
{
    long CreateWishList(long userId, string wishListName);
}
```

So, I want to unit test the `CreateWishListV1(...)` method, and to do that without database access, I need to mock what `Storage.CreateWishList(...)` returns. How do I do that?

UPDATE:

I'm trying something like this:

```
[Test]
public void CreateWishListTest()
{
    var mockAccess = new Mock<APIAccess>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    mockAccess.Setup(m => m.Device.CreateWishList(It.IsAny<long>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(123);

    var method = new CreateWishList();
    method.Storage = mockAccess.Object;

    long response = method.CreateWishListV1(12345, "test");

    Assert.IsTrue(response == 123, "WishList wasn't created.");
}
```

Had to change the `Storage` property on `APIAccess` to public as well.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? Why are you calling CreateWishListV1 on a mock? I think that's the method you want to test?

Comment: Yeah, I was doing it wrong. Updated the question; is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
var storage = new Mock<IStorage>();
storage.Setup(x => x.CreateWishList(It.IsAny<long>(), It.IsAny<string>())
       .Returns(10);
```

Then create your `CreateWishList` object with its own constructor accepting an `IStorage`.

```
var createWishList = new CreateWishList(storage.Object);
```

To unit test your `CreateWishList()` method you would write a separate test. This test should purely by to check the code in `CreateWishListV1()`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating the constructor?

Comment: You could make the `Storage` property public so the unit test can set it. Either way - you can't expect a unit test to assign a dependency when you're instantiating the dependency within the object.

Comment: Yes, you could inject the IStorage via a property, or set it via reflection. But creating a constructor that accepts the IStorage would be the cleanest way IMHO.